# Price increments in layered navigation

Tags: magento-1.7, price, layered-navigation

I have a question regarding price filters in the layered navigation.

On a top level category page:

http://todayscyclist.co.uk/bicycle-accessories.html

The price filter is split into just two options, in £1000 increments.

On the next level, the price filter is more sensible:

http://todayscyclist.co.uk/bicycle-accessories/bags-baskets/backpacks.html

this time in £10 increments.

In the admin I have layered nav set as follows:

Price Navigation Step Calculation: Automatic
Display Price Interval as One Price: No
Interval Division Limit: 9

Can anyone explain why the top level category is only returning two options, and why it is incrementing in £1000s?

Answer (score 5):

if you need to define custom price ranges for each category.follow the following steps

1) Go to System > Configuration > Catalog > Layered navigation.In this select Manual from "Price Navigation Step Calculation" and add following configuration from the following image.

[image]

2) Now go to any category and go to "Display Settings" tab their see at the bottom you can see "Layered Navigation Price Step" just give the Price Step for that cateogry. for more details see the image.

[image]

Price Step is basically the difference between the upper limit and lower limit in that price range.

Comment: Excellent. This should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Please open the given category settings in the admin, switch to the "display setting" and adjust the "Layered Navigation Price Step" for this category.